# Using X-editable with CodeIgniter 3 CSRF issue

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, csrf, x-editable

I'm using CodeIgniter 3 with CSRF enabled.  I have a page that is using X-editable library http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/index.html to do inline editing on that page.

Has anyone used X-editable with CodeIgniter and CSRF turned on?

My issue is when I have CSRF enabled I get the following CodeIgniter generated error:

```
<h1>An Error Was Encountered</h1>
<p>The action you have requested is not allowed.</p>
```

It works fine if I disable CSRF in CI.

What I do know is that I can't figure out a way to add a hidden field with the CSRF token when using the X-editable library, because the javascript library adds it's own form and form fields.  I know that CI's open_form() method adds the hidden field with the CSRF token automatically, but I have no option to use that with this particular library.

Any ideas? I have been stuck on this for a few days now.

This is the config.php file in my CI project

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'mycsrfname';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrfcookiename';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();
```

This is in the controller

```
$name = $this->input->post('name');
$value = $this->input->post('value');
$pk = $this->input->post('pk');
$result = $this->garage_model->editItem($name,$value,$pk);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to disable the CSRF token for your ajax call. Instead  you should send the token via params:

```
params: function(params) {
           params.csrfToken = $.cookie('csrfCookie');
           return params;
}
```

Comment: I absolutely agree about not disabling the CSRF token.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i've exclude urls CSRF for this script to work;
Look in config file at : $config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array('thename/ofcontrollertodisable');

Tell me if you find better solution !

Answer (score 0):

If it is still up to date, maybe this could help you.

To avoid Cross-site request forgery (CSRF) problem with Ajax, you can write following in a global page javascript:

```
var csfrData = {};
csfrData['<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>'] = '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>';
```

And then use this in your function:

```
// Attach CSFR data token
$.ajaxSetup({ data: csfrData });
```